# Formatting output with printf: truncating or padding

Tags: bash, awk, printf, output, formatted

I would like to produce the following output:

```
> Avril Stewart  99  54
> Sally Kinghorn 170 60
> John Young     195 120
> Yutte Schim... 250 40
```

As you can see, names shorter than 14 characters are padded with spaces. Names longer than 15 characters are truncated: 'Yutte Schimmelpenninck' truncates to 'Yutte Schim...'.

Here is what I have tried to achieve this (the variables `$name`, `$height`, and `$weight` are extracted from files, and a loop runs the `printf` command on each file data):

```
printf '%-14s -%3s -%3s\n' "$name" "$height" "$weight"
> Avril Stewart  99  54
> Sally Kinghorn 170 60
> John Young     195 120
> Yutte Schimmelpenninck 250 40
```

A `printf` one-liner is the desired solution.

What code will produce the first block of output?

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: And are you sure that's what you tried? I'd think your format string would produce `-` between the fields.

Comment: The fields are read in from a file of unknown length. The actual command issued is printf '%-14s -%3s -%3s\n' $name $weight $height.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before your `printf` command, you want to check if a name is longer than 14 characters, and if yes, truncate it and replace the last three characters with dots. This command does that:

```
(( ${#name} > 14 )) && name="${name:0:11}..."
```

It replaces `name` with its first eleven characters and appends `...`.

You also have to fix the `printf` format string: instead of

```
'%-14s -%3s -%3s\n'
```

it has to be

```
'%-14s %-3s -%-3s\n'
```

or you get results such as

```
Avril Stewart  - 99 - 54
```

Maybe that was just a typo, though, as your example output didn't have the hyphens.

All in all:

```
$ name='Avril Stewart'; weight=99; height=54
$ (( ${#name} > 14 )) && name="${name:0:11}..."
$ printf '%-14s %-3s %-3s\n' "$name" $weight $height
Avril Stewart  99  54
$ name='Sally Kinghorn'; weight=170; height=60
$ (( ${#name} > 14 )) && name="${name:0:11}..."
$ printf '%-14s %-3s %-3s\n' "$name" $weight $height
Sally Kinghorn 170 60
$ name='Yutte Schimmelpeninck'; weight=250; height=40
$ (( ${#name} > 14 )) && name="${name:0:11}..."
$ printf '%-14s %-3s %-3s\n' "$name" $weight $height
Yutte Schim... 250 40
```

So if you read this from a file, for example comma separated, you'd end up with a loop like this:

```
while IFS=, read -r name weight height; do
    (( ${#name} > 14 )) && name="${name:0:11}..."
    printf '%-14s %-3s %-3s\n' "$name" $weight $height
done < inputFile
```

resulting in

```
Avril Stewart  99  54
Sally Kinghorn 170 60
John Young     195 120
Yutte Schim... 250 40
```

---

I don't think it's possible in a one-liner. I experimented with the ternary operator and tried something like

```
printf '%s\n' $(( ${#name} > 14 ? "${name:0:11}..." : "$name" ))
```

but the problem here is that it only works for integers, and strings expand to zero in arithmetic context.

Answer (score 7):

a more idiomatic `awk` version will be

```
$ awk        '{v=$1 FS $2} 
  length(v)>14{v=substr(v,1,11)"..."}
              {printf "%-15s %-3d %-3d\n",v,$3,$4}' file     

Avril Stewart  99  54 
Sally Kinghorn 170 60 
John Young     195 120
Yutte Schim... 250 40
```

if you remove the `-` sign in %-3d, numbers will be right aligned as usual, however this the format you asked for.

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer -- Ignoring the final "...":

```
awk '{printf "%-14.14s %-3d %-3d\n",$1 FS $2,$3,$4}'
```

where `%-14.14s` does the padding + truncate formating of the name

Comment: This is what I needed to truncate with the optional printf argument to __git_ps1.  Note that you can truncate to 14 without padding with `%.14s` and I opted to skip the '...' since my goal is to limit my PS1 length.