# Horizontal and Vertical Line Spacing with a unknown variable length

Tags: linux, bash, sh, width, spacing

I am trying to print a output with specific format, where output is in a enclosed box. 
I am using "|" and "-" for creating it. The output I print in between the "|" are variables with Different number of characters.
This is messing my format.

I have tried the below code

```
nodename=$(hostname)
cpu=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | awk '/^processor/{print $3}' | wc -l)
echo " ------------------------------------------------------------------"  
echo "|                                                                  |" 
echo "|          This is Bash Scripting                                  |" 
echo "|                                                                  |" 
echo "|  1 - This Machine Name is $nodename                              |" 
echo "|  2 - This Machine has $cpu CPU's                                 |"
echo "|                                                                  |" 
echo " -------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

actual Result

```
" ------------------------------------------------------------------"  
"|                                                                  |" 
"|          This is Bash Scripting                                  |" 
"|                                                                  |" 
"|  1 - This Machine Name is test                              |" 
"|  2 - This Machine has 8 CPU's                                 |"
"|                                                                  |" 
" -------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Expected result

```
" ------------------------------------------------------------------"  
"|                                                                  |" 
"|          This is Bash Scripting                                  |" 
"|                                                                  |" 
"|  1 - This Machine Name is test                                   |" 
"|  2 - This Machine has 8 CPU's                                    |"
"|                                                                  |" 
" -------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: [Bash add trailing spaces to justify string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/354092), [How do I print some text in bash and pad it with spaces to a certain width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6345429/608639), [Padding characters in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4409399/608639), [Formatting output with printf: truncating or padding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36121180/608639), etc.

Comment: `grep -c processor /proc/cpuinfo`. One process instead of three. You don't need `awk` to extract the processor number when all you are doing is counting how many there are.

Answer (score 4):

Use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf "|  1 - This Machine Name is %-39s|\n" "$nodename"
```

You can specify the right space padding with `%-39s`